# How to install with terratest a chart with dependencies

Tags: go, kubernetes, integration-testing, kubernetes-helm, terratest

I'm using terratest to do unit test and integration test of a big helm chart. This chart has a lot of other chart dependencies, and the definition looks something like this (there are many other dependencies):

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: chart
description: A Helm chart for deploying Ditto BigPeer Anywhere
type: application
kubeVersion: < 1.28.3
version: 1.19.0
appVersion: 1.19.0
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    condition: feature.ingress-nginx.enabled
    repository: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
    version: 4.8.2
    tags:
      - ingress
```

And my code in go to do the integration test looks like this:

```golang
package test

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/helm"
    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/k8s"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestPodDeploysContainerImage(t *testing.T) {
    helmChartPath := "../"
    kubectlOptions := k8s.NewKubectlOptions("", "", "default")

    options := &helm.Options{
        ValuesFiles: []string{
            "../values.yaml",
        },
    }
    releaseName := "chartname"

    helm.Install(t, options, helmChartPath, releaseName)

    // here comes the test logic
}
```

My environment is minikube and I have installed the chart manually and it works, but when a run the tests with go, I get the following error:

```
error while running command: exit status 1; Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: An error occurred while checking for chart dependencies. You may need to run `helm dependency build` to fetch missing dependencies: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: ingress-nginx, cert-manager, strimzi-kafka-operator, consul
```

I already ran the dependency build but it doesn't change anything, the *.tgz* files in the charts folder are downloaded, but terratest is not able to use them, how can I run the tests?